# Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'slice'

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
    columns: [{ 
        field: "id" 
    },{ 
        field: "question"     
    },{ 
        field: "order" 
    },{ 
        field: "type" 
    },{
        command: [ "edit" , "destroy"], 
        width: 280 
    }],
    dataSource: {
        type: "Data",
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "@Url.Action("getAlldetails","IPPFnew")"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This is my code but I get the below error:

> 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'slice'

Comment: `slice` is a method of `array`

Comment: Just a wild guess the error might be coming from`ajax` call `"@Url.Action("getAlldetails","IPPFnew")`